# Async calls get stuck at HttpClient.SendAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, botframework, bots

I am using Microsoft Bot framework (SDK v3) to create a QnA bot. While calling the QnAMaker API, the execution gets stuck at HttpCleint.SendAsync.

I have tried calling ConfigureAwait(false) on all the async calls.
I have tried adding .Result at end of function calls. 
Both doesn't seem to work.

```
[Serializable]
public class QnAMakerService
{
    private string qnaServiceHostName;
    private string knowledgeBaseId;
    private string endpointKey;

    public QnAMakerService()
    {
        qnaServiceHostName = "foo";
        knowledgeBaseId = "bar";
        endpointKey = "foo";

    }
    async Task<string> Post(string uri, string body)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "EndpointKey " + endpointKey);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    public async Task<string> GetAnswer(string question)
    {
        string uri = qnaServiceHostName + "/qnamaker/knowledgebases/" + knowledgeBaseId + "/generateAnswer";
        string questionJSON = @"{'question': '" + question + "'}";

        var response = await Post(uri, questionJSON);

        var answers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAAnswer>(response);
        if (answers.answers.Count > 0)
        {
            return answers.answers[0].answer;
        }
        else
        {
            return "No good match found.";
        }
    }
}


[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    QnAMakerService qna = new QnAMakerService();


    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {

            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

            var q = await qna.GetAnswer(activity.Text);

            // return our reply to the user
            Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"{q}");
            connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(reply);
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

}
```

The execution stops after the SendAsync call with a 500 internal server error excception.

I think the asynchonous code is getting blocked somewhere, but I don't know where.

EDIT : The same block of code(to call the API) works if I try it in a console application.

Comment: `@"{'question': '" + question + "'}"` single quotes are not properly formatted JSON. I suspect this may be why the server is returning a 500 on the send.

Comment: I have tried with double quotes, but nothing changed. I tried calling the API from Postman, and it returns the correct response(both with single and double quotes).
Also, the API returns a bad parameter response if there is any problem with the JSON.

Comment: @zeroex use a singleton HttpClient and not create and dispose a new one each time. You may be running out of sockets. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/